# Como obtener un solo valor de un Json

Tags: c#, json

Tengo mi response que viene en json lo obtengo de la siguiente forma:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);
                    String json = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Con un WriteLine me muestra:

```
[{"id":"1","correo":"alpha@e.com","clave":"123456","numero":"+1 8XX-307-7455"}]
```

El problema es que solo quiero el `numero` como puedo obtenerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes intentar es convertir tu response en un objeto JSON de la siguiente manera

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);
String json = sr.ReadToEnd();

dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Y una vez que tengas el objeto puedes acceder a uno de sus atributos de la siguiente manera:

```
    // el [0] por que es un JsonArray y define la posición en cual buscar.
    var numero = jsonObj[0]["numero"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(numero);
```

Mira he probado en este compilador online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wgmqpd

De todas formas te dejo el código que utilice para probarlo:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String json = ("[{\"id\":\"1\",\"correo\":\"alpha@e.com\",\"clave\":\"123456\",\"numero\":\"+1 8XX-307-7455\"}]");
        dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObj);
        var numero = jsonObj[0]["numero"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(numero);            
    }
}
```

Comment: _Error_ Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' no contiene una definición para 'createdBy'.'

Comment: he editado la respuesta y he probado, espero sea de tu ayuda

Comment: @ManuelMorales puedes mirar el link que puse en la respuesta y comprobar que funciona